# Python, how to sort dataframe by string column in ascending

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BGLa.png)

The campaign is stored as a string, and I want to sort by the campaign column in ascending order. I tried converting it to an integer with the following code, but it still only sorts as it does in the screenshot (1,10,2,20 instead of 1,2,10,20)

```
df[["campaign"]] = df[["campaign"]].apply(pd.to_numeric)
df.sort_values(by=['campaign'])
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Don't use `apply`. Do `df['campaign'] = pd.to_numeric(df['campaign'])`. Also, `sort_by` does not modify your dataframe in-place. You need to assign it back `df = df.sort_values(by=['campaign'])`

Comment: Ahhhhh, right I did forget to assign it back. Thank you! It works now

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: Also, please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to convert string values in the campaign column to numeric values:

`df["campaign"] = pd.to_numeric(df["campaign"], errors='coerce')`

to sort based on campaign column use:

`df.sort_values("campaign", inplace=True)`